# How can I set MX records and confirm emails?

Tags: email, domain, g-suite, mx-record

I am working with a friend who has two domains, foo.com and bar.com, and would like to use Google Apps to handle email for those domains.

This is something of a virgin install, and Google Apps wants to confirm that they can receive email at mail@foo.com and mail@bar.com.

Is there some dirt simple offering where they can point their mx records, receive an email sent to mail@foo.com / mail@bar.com, and move on to Google Apps?

Comment: How about webmail through whatever registrar has the domains?

Comment: I have never seen this requirement before.  Aren't there other options to confirm by creating a DNS record?  If yes, then use those instead

Comment: I concur with Zoredache - you can use DNS records or meta tags on the website (if one exists) to validate. Use these instead.

Comment: How did you go with this @Jonathan Hayward ?

Comment: It ended up being worked out by other people, and I was only given a vague explanation of what had happened. In other words, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to post a screenshot of the verification page as this seems like a strange requirement.

Google usually offers several forms of verification, usually adding a cname is a quick and easy way to verify your domain (you can login to your domain admin area with your registrar, the company you purchased your domain from and manage DNS records there).

Look for "alternative verification methods" to see what google offers http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60216

Comment: Google does not require email verification for Google Apps -- many, many new customers are setting up their mail for the first time with Google. I agree with Drew that you should post a screenshot.